# Change select selected with Jquery data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code for Jquery i just started working with Jquery but i have a bit of knowledge with Javascript.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

         $("#d_or_t").val('navbar');//<?php echo "cms18"; ?>
         // if ('<?php $key ?>'== '<?php  ?>') {};
    });
$('#selector').on('change',function(){
     //alert($(this).find("option:selected").html()) ; 
     var data = document.getElementById('url_option');
     var current = $(this).find("option:selected").html();
     alert(current);
     //alert(current);

   //(data.dataset.domains);   
});
</script>
```

And my HTML select box is this one i have three of them and i want that when i change the URL select box the other 2 select box change to an data

```
<form action="php-json.php" id="form" method="post">
                        <select name="selector" id="selector" class="form-control">
                            <!-- opzoeken wat de colon : betekend daar  -->
                            <?php foreach ($aUrls as $key => $value) 
                                : ?> 
                                <option id="url_option" data-domains="<?php echo $aDomains[$key]; ?>" data-template="<?php echo $aTemplates[$key]; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $value;?>
                                </option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select> 
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <select name="d_or_t" id="d_or_t" class="form-control">
                        <?php foreach ($aDomains as $key => $value) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option><?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>   
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <select name="t_or_t" id="d_or_t" class="form-control">
                        <?php foreach ($aTemplates as $key => $value) : ?> 
                        <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value;?></option><?php endforeach; ?>


                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="veranderen">Veranderen</button> 
                </div>
            </div> 
            </form>
```

Comment: Where will the other two `select` elements get their data from?

Comment: `Id` for `<option>` will not work.

Comment: you want to change the content of other 2 dropdowm based on first one??

Comment: This is not very clear what you actually for and your code doesn't really make much sense. If you can't explain your problem then you don't understand it. I would suggest going away and really thinking about what you want before posting questions.

Comment: not the content but the selected one like this $("#d_or_t").val('navbar'); but in this case i want navbar to be the value of array from the data i made with php